# Projectiles follow the Player Movement (Unity2D)

Tags: unity-game-engine

Im trying to make a 2d platformer-like game, and when it comes to projectiles they kinda follow the player movement. If I shoot in the right direction and I move to the left, the projectile will change its position and start moving to the left from the GameObject assigned as "gun". The "gun" is a child of the player so I always shoot from the same position.
Edit:
Here is the code for shooting:
Edit2: if() statements are for ammo

```
void OnFire(InputValue value)
    {
        if(kopanScore.kopanNumber > 0)
        {
        Instantiate(projectile, projectileSpawn);
        kopanScore.MinusKopanScore();
        }
        
        else if(kopanScore.kopanNumber <= 0)
        {
            return;
        }
    }
```

Comment: you have to add your code

Comment: does the projectile has any script attached?

Comment: Is projectile Spawn the child of the player? What is the speed value when you move to the opposite position? If you stand still, you shoot left, but then move right, does the bullet follow you anyway?

Comment: the projectile Spawn is a child of the player. But still I dont think the bullets should behave this way